# Как динамически менять пункт drawer menu

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

У меня есть 4 пункта в `Drawer Menu` и у первого пункта по умолчанию visible = false(то есть он не должен отображаться при старте) и мне нужно динамически делать его видимым и при этом текст добавить. 
Я делаю таким образом и это работает:

`public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

.......

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true).setTitle("Москва - Новосибирск");
```

Этот `Activity` является родителем для остальных `Activity`. И если вот так прописать нормально работает. А мне нужно динамически отображать этот пункт, то есть чтобы он был невидимым пока `SecondActivity` не откроется.

Попробовал так:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

public NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout fullLayout;
public boolean isLastResult;

@Override
public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
    ..........

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    if (!isLastResult){
        Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true).setTitle("Москва - Новосибирск");
    }
.........
```

**SecondActivity:**

```
public class SecondActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
    ........    
    isLastResult = false;
    ........
```

Но все равно никакого изменения, то есть не становится видимым. Еще попробовал наоборот в начале обьявить `public boolean isLastResult = false` и в `SecondActivity` в `onCreate` `isLastResult = true` и проверку таким образом:

```
if (isLastResult){
        Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true).setTitle("Москва - Новосибирск");
    }
```

и пункт всегда отображается, то есть еще до того, как `SecondActivity` не открылся.

**Вопрос:** Подскажите, что не так делаю, что неправильно?

Comment: Вообще не очень понятно зачем переопределять setContentView... Попробуйте его неизменным оставить, и просто сделать один свой метод, в коем и менять дровер. Метод этот вызывайте во всех активити сразу после вызова стандартоного setContentView

Answer (score 1):

```
BaseActivity значение переменной isLastResult по умолчанию false
соответственно в первой активити этот код будет выполняться
if (!isLastResult){
    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true).setTitle("Москва - Новосибирск");
}

Тебе нужно выставить значение isLastResult = true;
```

Comment: Странно, Не реагирует!

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию

```
public boolean isLastResult;
```

инициализируется значением `false`.

Если вам надо, чтобы в первой он был `true`, а во второй `false`, то так и объявляйте это в переменной класса.

Comment: Вообще никакой реакции, мне кажется почему-то проверку он не видит. А без проверки работает...